# Safe to open a flash file offline?

Tags: anonymity, security

I've read that opening files using certain programs such as Flash or Word can automatically send out information from your computer which may compromise anonymity when using Tor.

What I'm wondering is, if I download the files (which in itself is safe as far as I know), disconnect from the internet, and then open them while offline, will the information still be sent out somehow (say, the next time I go online)?

Answer (score 3):

It's safe unless the script exploits a security issue in Flash that allows it to persist (by installing a helper program that gets auto-started for example). This is occasionally possible through security issues in Flash/Word/etc, but much less of a threat than the "normal" ability to connect to random destinations on the internet.